# leiningen uberjar - add external jar at runtime

Tags: clojure, leiningen, uberjar

I am trying to see how I can add a directory and an external jar to the classpath when making a leiningen uberjar.

The reason is that I need to distribute a jar but some dependencies (jdbc driver for example) cannot be compiled into the uberjar due to licencing restrictions.

I would also like to provide certain external resources such as properties for logging and configuration external to the jar.

Normally in java or spring boot I would use the appropriate command line option to change the classpath. However -cp does not find the jar etc

Is there a way to do this or an appropriate plugin?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add the jar as a resource in the :dev profile. Then it is added to the classpath. The dev profile is for the local development and not packaged into the uberjar.

```
:profiles {
         :uberjar {:aot :all}
         :dev {:resource-paths ["no-redist/commercial-jdbc-driver.jar"]}}
```

At 'production' time with the uberjar you need set the classpath then manually:

```
java -cp no-redist/commercial-jdbc-driver.jar;your-app-uber-jar.jar main.namespace
```

Afaik when using the -jar flag, it uses the dependencies in the jar file, whatever is linked and referred to in there. Combining -cp and -jar might not work.

Another way is to refer to the no-distributable jar file in the jar manifest (META-INF/MANIFEST.MF):

```
Class-Path: no-redist/commercial-jdbc-driver.jar
```

The the java -jar your-app-uber-jar.jar would look for the jar in the folder no-redist/commercial-jdbc-driver.jar in the local directory. Add this in leinigen like:

```
:manifest {"Class-Path" "no-redist/commercial-jdbc-driver.jar"}
```

Comment: I understand that but my main issue is how do I then get the uberjar to see the commercial driver. Whenever I put the jar it does not see it. If I use the -cp option this appears to be ignored by the bootloader and I get class not found errors. Similar with resources I have asked to be on the classpath - it does not seem to look outside of the uberjar for anything

Comment: Updated answer to be more details for running the uberjar with the no redistributable jar

Comment: Thanks, @Gamlor, I had a similar problem and adding a manifest resolved it.   
  :manifest {"Class-Path" "resources/stanford-postagger-4.2.0.jar"}